# turtlebot3 Rviz launch using more than one path

Tags: python, navigation, ros, robotics, gazebo-simu

hey guys so i'm trying to launch turtlebot3_gazebo_rviz but i'm getting this error.

```
 roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_gazebo_rviz.launch
 ... logging to /home/zac1405/.ros/log/78418374-e1c4-11ec-86d1-000c295c3592/roslaunch- 
 ubuntu-10618.log
 Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
 Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
 Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

 xacro: in-order processing became default in ROS Melodic. You can drop the option.
 started roslaunch server http://ubuntu:40921/

 SUMMARY
 ========

 PARAMETERS
  * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
  * /robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency: 50.0
  * /robot_state_publisher/tf_prefix: 
  * /rosdistro: melodic
  * /rosversion: 1.14.13

 NODES
   /
     robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
rviz (rviz/rviz)

 ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

 process[robot_state_publisher-1]: started with pid [10693]
 ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rviz/rviz]: rviz
 ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
 ROS path [1]=/home/zac1405/catkin_ws/src
 ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/melodic/share
```

I suspect that the launcher was not able to choose the right path to start with, which is why it shakes three different paths. My idea was to remove path 0 and path 2 and use only the path with index 1. I hope my expectation is correct, otherwise I hope someone can help me.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after some research I can tell you that my interpretation was wrong, to solve the problem simply install ros-melodic.rviz

```
sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-rviz
```

i hope i was helpfull